# How to display JSON sting in datagridview (cell merging)

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, merge

I need to display my JSON sting in c# windows form application's `dataGridView`. so I use this code and its works properly.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string myDynamicJSON = "[ { 'Company': 'Company A', 'ProjectName': 'Project A', 'Developer': 'No developer assigned', 'Hour': 0, 'Overtime': 0, 'Contribution': '0' }, { 'Company': 'Company A', 'ProjectName': 'Project B', 'Developer': 'paul', 'Hour': 36, 'Overtime': 27, 'Contribution': '71.5909%' }, { 'Company': 'Company A', 'ProjectName': 'Project B', 'Developer': 'kalpa', 'Hour': 16, 'Overtime': 9, 'Contribution': '28.4091%' }, { 'Company': 'Company B', 'ProjectName': 'Project C', 'Developer': 'shane', 'Hour': 40, 'Overtime': 14, 'Contribution': '78.2609%' }, { 'Company': 'Company B', 'ProjectName': 'Project C', 'Developer': 'kal', 'Hour': 10, 'Overtime': 5, 'Contribution': '21.7391%' }, { 'Company': 'Company C', 'ProjectName': 'Project D', 'Developer': 'No developer assigned', 'Hour': 0, 'Overtime': 0, 'Contribution': '0' }, { 'Company': 'Company D', 'ProjectName': 'Project E', 'Developer': 'No developer assigned', 'Hour': 0, 'Overtime': 0, 'Contribution': '0' } ]";

        dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myDynamicJSON);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myObject;
    }
}
```

this is the output table this code gives to me.

[image]

But this my requirement. I need to merge company column based on company.this image shows my requirement.

[image]

how can I get this output.

Comment: DGV doesn't support real cell merging.

Comment: @TaW So how can I do this. have any possible way to do this

Comment: Try [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+datagridview+cell+merging&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)